# No such module 'FBSDKLoginKit'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podfile

I just copied my project from my back up folder to another folder in desktop and its giving me this error. I have updated my pod again after removing FBSDKLoginKit still it's not working. If I remove this module and then build also some other pod will give the same error.

please don't mark it as duplicate as I need the root cause for this issue rather than the temporary solutions provided in different other threads like this one 
[No Such Module 'FBSDKLoginKit' Xcode 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276076/no-such-module-fbsdkloginkit-xcode-9)

Comment: please dont mark it as duplicate as I need the root cause for this issue rather than the temporary solutions provided in different other threads like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47276076/no-such-module-fbsdkloginkit-xcode-9

Comment: ok... try again.... delete your pod folder and derived data and then again reinstall the pod afterthat open workspace.. build and run

Comment: I read in some thread that we need to be cautious while deleting the pod and related files . Let me try once .

Comment: its actually path problem with sdk.. you can see the framework path in build settings it will show you old path still. i think so

Comment: Oh ok .. I was thinking the same as it gave me some link error initially but it’s disappeared in the subsequent builds . Then only pod related errors started showing up . I will check that too . Thanks much .

Comment: Did everything still its giving me error " No such module 'FBSDKLoginKit" IS there anything wrong with this sdk ? These three gives the error . rest all looks right 1) FBSDKLoginKit 2)FBSDKShareKit 3) SVProgressHUD. But the strange thing is all those were working perfect till a day before. where to change the framework path in build settings ?

Comment: As a last try i just removed all the code for facebook log in from my app and tried again . Now getting this error " ld: framework not found FBSDKLoginKit clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
" Dont know why the same pod is causing the trouble . is there anything else i need to remove in order to complete the pod removal.

Comment: removed all facebook log in related pods from my pod file and its working . But still I am not getting the root cause of the issue as this is just a workaround . Need to find out the solution for this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got a fix for this . I used command + B to build my project, the errors related to SVProgressHUD,FBSDKLoginKit and FBSDKShareKit went away.

Edit : The actual issue is there is a bug with Xcode wherein its not recognizing the pods already installed and added to the project.Thats why the module not found error during compile time.  I am getting the same build error with many other pods afterwards also.Its happening only at times that too unexpectedly .The only way is to build the project multiple times until it recognizes the module and the error is gone .This sounds crazy but no other way so far.please update here if someone finds a permanent fix for this . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by going into Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme and then within the Build options I checked "Find implicit dependencies". Seemed to work for me, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by deleting entire Pods/ folder, then running Pod install after (I know you already solved it, but in case someone else runs into it. ).